# Do incorporeal creatures trigger symbol spells normally?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, incorporeal

As per [*symbol of death*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/symbolOfDeath.html), symbol spells can have one or more of the following triggers:

1. Creature looks at a symbol
2. Creature reads a symbol
3. Creature touches a symbol
4. Creature passes over a symbol
5. Creature passes through a portal bearing a symbol

Presumably, there wouldn't be any issues with an incorporeal creature such as a ghost triggering 1 or 2, as it can see normally unless specified otherwise and I don't believe there's any reason for its sight to work unusually. With regards to 3-5, however, are there any quirks that I should keep in mind? Does an incorporeal creature passing through a door still trigger #5? Can an incorporeal creature passing through a wall trigger #3?

Comment: I think you will have to edit the question to use a different *symbol* as the example, if you want to get proper discussion of these five points, since undead are immune to *symbol of death* anyway. (The Undead creature type grants "Immunity to [...] death effects".)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie While the overwhelming majority of incorporeal creatures are undead, it’s not strictly required. [Animate dreams](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/animate-dream) are incorporeal outsiders, [colors out of space](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/colour-out-of-space) are incorporeal **oozes** of all things, and [*dust form*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dust-form) makes the caster incorporeal.

Comment: @KRyan That's a good point I overlooked. The 'such as a ghost' + 'symbol of death' leads me to believe the asker is thinking specifically of undead, but the general principle doesn't, yeah.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## #3 is the only one that incorporeal creatures cannot do

Incorporeal creatures cannot touch the physical world; that is why they have Str —. They can only touch *ghost touch* objects. This is, more-or-less, the **only** inherent function of being incorporeal. An incorporeal creature still can see (#1 and #2) and has a location/space (#4 and #5).

Many incorporeal creatures have a way to optionally “manifest” to touch things, so **those** creatures could touch a *symbol* if for some reason they wished to do so. This is not a default ability inherently granted by being incorporeal, however.

Furthermore, most incorporeal creatures are undead, which means they are immune to many spells – including the *symbols of death*, *insanity*, and *sleep*. Again, this is because they are undead, not because they are incorporeal. Incorporeal-but-living creatures would be affected by these spells as normal (at least, assuming nothing **else** is protecting them, e.g. *death ward* or *mind blank*).

Comment: Casper: "I can't push the frobnicate button!" Mage: "Drat, looks like I'll have to find some way to work *ghost touch* into a symbol of frobnication!"